# Button height is smaller than specified in CSS

Tags: css, height

I have this simple button here: http://jsfiddle.net/u6t5A/

If you look in Firebug at the "Computed styles" tab, you will see that the height is 24px, but the referred CSS rule is the one stating height: 30px (please see snapshot here: http://twitpic.com/dfwp8j )

Can anyone tell me why the height of the displayed button is not 30px (as specified in the CSS), but instead it's 24px?

Does it have to do with line-height? Or maybe with inline-block?

**This is the code:**

HTML:

```
<button>Bla bla bla</button>
```

CSS:

```
body, td, th {
    font-size: small;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;

    margin: 0 0.7em 0 0;
    padding: 0px 5px 4px 5px;

    height: 30px;

    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;

    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#e9e9e9));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e9e9e9);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e9e9e9);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e9e9e9);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e9e9e9);

    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;

    line-height: 130%;

    color: #464646;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
    -moz-border-radius: 11px;
    border-radius: 11px;

    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;

    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 1px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 1px;
}
```

Comment: I get computed height as 30px in firefox

Comment: I check in firefox, safari and chrome, I do have a height of 30px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the CSS box-model, an element's size is `height`+`padding`+`border`. If you have in example the following css:

```
.my-element { height: 10px; padding: 2px; border: 2px solid #000; }
```

Than it's total height would be 10+2*2+2*2=18px. (2*2 because you have to add padding at top and bottom, AND border at the top and bottom).

Now if you look to the size of your button (what firebug says at least), that's exactly right: the height you stated (30px) minus the padding, minus the border.

A button behaves as if you explicitly gave the box-sizing property the `border-box` value. This means that the *outer* width of the element will be the height you defined, but the *inner* height will be the outer height minus padding and border. Now if you give the button the `content-box` value on the `box-sizing` property, it will add up the padding and border again.

But please note; your button is actually 30 px high, but only the *inner height* of the content is less (24px that is).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I knew about box-sizing, but what confused me is why Firebug displays height:24 and then the rule with height:30. It should have displayed maybe something like contentHeight:24, or innerHeight:24... This made me think that there is some of the other rules like line-height or inline-block that somehow affect the height; but I tried to remove then in turns, with no success.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Height includes padding and border, which for these purposes are 6 (1px each top and bottom border and 4px bottom padding. 30 - 6 = 24px

Answer (score 2):

Sorin,

padding-bottom (4px) + border-top (1px) + border-bottom (1px) = 6px

6px - height (30px) = 24px

So, increase the button's height:

```
button { height: 36px; }
```

Answer (score -2):

I applaud your attempt at trying to be dynamic but stick doing dynamic stuff with page layouts. You're using percentages and other relative values such as `em` for values. If you want pixel precision you need to use pixel `px` values. Your approach becomes even more horribly subjective when you open that content on *any* Linux machine.